# What is the most user-friendly way to ask for mandatory CLI arguments when there are many arguments?

Tags: command-line-interface, argparse

I am building a CLI for a securities trading website using argparse in Python. The purpose of the CLI is not commercial, so there are no requirements that come with offering a commercial product, though I'd like to make it as usable as possible.

My primary question was relating to the best way to ask for required arguments when there are many of them. For one action 'trade', multiple arguments (6) are required. I'm concerned that requiring too many arguments would be confusing for the user to deal with. Example execution below:

`python program.py trade arg_a arg_b arg_c arg_d arg_e arg_f`

I felt that it might be difficult and confusing for the user to have so many required arguments to specify and was debating between the following choices.

1. Require all arguments.
2. Make all required arguments optional and prompt for missing arguments after running.

For this option, the user can specify as many arguments as they want. The program will ask for the remaining arguments during runtime.

3. Require some arguments on the command line and require some arguments during runtime.

For this option, a few arguments (i.e. a, b, c) can only be specified on the command line, and a few arguments can only be specified during runtime (i.e. d, e, f).

4. Allow the user to specify a file containing the necessary arguments.

I'm currently leaning towards requiring all arguments (choice 1), though I do not have much experience with CLI design. I'm wondering if there is a reasonably definitive answer on the best way to deal with such a situation.

Comment: Have you thought about using a .config file, as well as cli arguments? Be sensible and predictable about defaults, and give terse but adequate output on which setting will be used and what the source of it is.

Comment: There's no one right way.  The usual POSIX/linux practice for the commandline is to have optionals (flagged), possibly many, and a small number of required positionals, most often things like file names.   If you give the optional arguments reasonable defaults, you don't have to worry if the user supplies them or not.  `argparse` does allow you to "require" flagged arguments, or accept multiple values (`nargs`).  Positionals may also take variable number of values.  But always keep in mind the `usage`, how you'll explain things.  The simpler is usually better.